# Load JSON file from nested array

Tags: json, jquery

I have script jquery for load json from file like this :

```
$.getJSON( "text.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

and result :

- value
- value
- value
- value
- [object Object]
- [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

how do i load [object Object]

maybe i want to be like this :

- value
- value
- value
- value
- value{}
  -value
  -value
  -value
- value[]
  -value{}
     -value
     -value
     -value
  -value{}
      -value
      -value
      -value
  -value{}
       -value
       -value
       -value
  -value{}
       -value
       -value
       -value
  -value{}
       -value
       -value
       -value

my question what script for that. thanx

(text.json)

```
{
"sender":"",
"status":
    {
        "status":"DELIVERED",
        "date_time":"2013-09-30 15:00:00",
    },
"history":
    [   
            {
                "status":"DELIVERED",
                "date_time":"2013-09-30 15:00:00",
            },
            {
                "status":"BAD ADDRESS-UNKNOWN COMPANY",
                "date_time":"2013-09-26 07:45:26",
            }
    ]
}
```

> I will try this script bellow but not display :(
>
> ```
> $.getJSON( "text.json", function( data ) {
>   var items = [];
>   $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
>          $.each( val, function( key1, val2 ) {
>     items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
>   });  
>      items.push( "<lo id='" + key2 + "'>" + val2 + "</lo>" );
> ```
>
> });
>         $( "", {
>           "class": "my-new-list",
>           html: items.join( "" )
>         }).appendTo( "body" );
>       });

Comment: see if this example helps you http://jsfiddle.net/qkzvm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if the variable is an object and if it is start another iteration to get those list items  etc...  Note this is not a complete solution depending on how you want your list to look but should get you started in the right direction.

```
$.getJSON( "text.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
   if(typeof(val) === 'object')
   {
      $.each( val, function( key2, val2 ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key2 + "'>" + val2 + "</li>" );
      });
   }
   else
     items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});
$( "<ul/>", {
  "class": "my-new-list",
  html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Here is a fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/qkzvm/

And an example using your JSON.

http://jsfiddle.net/qkzvm/1/